# How to load the data into existing table in postgresql database in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a web application using Django where I am trying to load the user data during signup into the PostgreSQL database but how to insert the user data into the database.

I have executed:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
python manage.py migrate
```

it is creating the new table.

But I want the data to be inserted from the form to be saved in the database.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=provisioning'
        },
        'NAME': 'OneClickProvisioning',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Hanu@2789',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='FirstName',
        max_length=32
    )

    lname = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='LastName',
        max_length=32
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from Provisioning import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', views.home),
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            password =  userObj['password']
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
                User.objects.create_user(username, password)
                user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login.html')
```

When clicking on the signup button, it has to store the user input data into the database and redirect to the login page once the user has been registered.

Comment: How are you claiming that data is not being inserted into the database? Did you cross check in django admin users page?

Comment: have you commit?

Comment: its because form is invalid try printing form.errors you have given fname and lname and trying to access username and password which are not part of UserRegistrationForm